# build a simple BlackVarianceSurface in python

Tags: python, quantlib, quantlib-swig

I am trying to build a BlackVarianceSurface so that I can compare interpolation result with mine. What i did is

```python
todaydate = Date(1, January, 2010) 
maturity=[]
for i in range(24):
  maturity.append(Date(1, January, 2010)+Period(i, Months))

k = range(10, 90, 10)
vol = abs(random.randn(24, 8)).transpose().tolist()

volsurf = BlackVarianceSurface(todaydate, TARGET(), maturity, k, vol, Actual365Fixed())
```

i am using numpy matrix. is it wrapped into quantlib Matrix? Is there anything I am doing wrong

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the QuantLib wrappers don't take numpy matrices.  You'll have to convert them to simple lists of lists before passing them to the class constructor.

Another couple of issues I came across while trying your code:

- you'll have to transpose the matrix.  The len() of the outer list must equal the number of strikes and that of the inner lists must equal the number of maturities.
- you're using a today's date which is later than most maturities (maybe a typo above, or a copy/paste gone awry?). Anyway, the constructor will raise an exception, so you'll have to fix your dates one way or the other.  Also, you might want to set `Settings.instance().evaluationDate` to your today's date.

Comment: Thanks, Luigi. the assertion system is very comprehensive. it guides me through correcting version until when I get
RuntimeError: dates must be sorted unique!
but it looks like maturity is sorted and unique

Comment: After I change reference date earlier than first maturity date, it works.